# SELECT TABLE REPEAT TABLE LOOP MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, select, while-loop, insert

First off I am loving Stack Overflow, you are all so helpful..

I have a situation, I have a Table with data like this;

```
1 - Apple
2 - Bananna
3 - Pear
4 - Orange
5 - Plum
```

I could do something like this;

```
DECLARE @C INT = 0
WHILE (@C < 3) 
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tbl1 (ID,Name)
        SELECT * FROM tbl2 -- THIS WILL CONTAIN 5 Rows
        SET @C+=1
    END
```

So it would end up like this;

```
1 - Apple
2 - Bananna
3 - Pear
4 - Orange
5 - Plum
1 - Apple
2 - Bananna
3 - Pear
4 - Orange
5 - Plum
1 - Apple
2 - Bananna
3 - Pear
4 - Orange
5 - Plum
```

Now I could go ahead and put a while loop 3 times and be done, however this select script is to be repeated 400,000 times so using insert->select->insert->select, etc would cause massive overload. What I want to do is something like this;

```
INSERT INTO tbl1
SELECT 
   ID,
   Name,
   @C = COUNT(ID) 
FROM tbl2 
WHERE @C < 3
```

I don't know if this is even possible, however the other method is using COMMIT but I don't know how to use that effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `GO` to execute the `INSERT` statement as a batch

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.T1', N'U') IS NULL
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1
    ([Id] int, [name] varchar(7)) ;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.T2', N'U') IS NULL
CREATE TABLE dbo.T2
    ([Id] int, [name] varchar(7)) ;

INSERT INTO T1
    ([Id], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 'Apple'),
    (2, 'Bananna'),
    (3, 'Pear'),
    (4, 'Orange'),
    (5, 'Plum')
;

INSERT INTO dbo.T2
(Id,[name])
SELECT T.Id
        ,T.[name] 
FROM dbo.T1 T 
GO 100

DROP TABLE dbo.T1
DROP TABLE dbo.T2
```

Comment: That works for me, See updated answer for complete sample solution